# How to simplify geometry in a triangle mesh in AutoCAD?

Tags: 3d, blender, autocad, dxf

It's been a long time since I've worked with AutoCAD and I have a question that is taking time to solve. I apologize if my question is not too clear enough.

I have a simple 3D model made in Blender I need to export it to Autocad in dxf format. In Blender I have dissolved faces to simplify the geometry of the mesh.
When I export my model to Autocad, I have new triangles on the faces (see image). My client asks me to remove that triangulation and make the mesh as clear as possible.

**Screenshot with the model in Blender and AutoCAD**

[image]

Is there a quick way in AutoCAD to simplify the geometry to eliminate those triangles? Is the methodology I'm applying correct? Please note that my client requests that the final file be in dxf or dwg.

Comment: The problem needs to be resolved in Blender, changing the DXF entity they use for planar faces. If they used Region entity, for example, those additional lines would not have been there...

Comment: I have been reading that it is more advisable to use the FBX format to avoid triangulation in AutoCAD.
 Also, it seems that currently in Blender it is better to use the FBX exporter as opposed to the DXF file export add-on, as it is less developed.
I have done tests and it seems that this solves my problem. Thank you very much for your response @abenci